# What are the ways to do numeric testing in bash?

Tags: bash, numbers, testing

Suppose I have variable "x" in bash. How can I test if it's some number?

I tried `if x=5; then echo "it is 5"; fi` but that doesn't work,

then I tried `if x==5; then echo "it is 5"; fi` but that also doesn't work,

then I tried `if [x==5]; then echo "it is 5"; fi` but that also doesn't work,

then I tried `if [[x==5]]; then echo "it is 5"; fi` but that also doesn't work,

then I tried `if [[x=5]]; then echo "it is 5"; fi` but that also doesn't work,

then I tried `if [x=5]; then echo "it is 5"; fi` but that also doesn't work,

then I tried `if [x -eq 5]; then echo "it is 5"; fi` but that also doesn't work,

then I tried `if [[x -eq 5]]; then echo "it is 5"; fi` and it finally worked.

I am lost. Bash seems to be hell. Why so many ways didn't work? And only the last one did?

Can't bash adopt `if x==5; then ...; fi` syntax?

Thanks, Boda Cydo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
if [ "$x" = 5 ]; then echo "it is 5"; fi
```

Note that `[` is a command in itself; you may find that it's symlinked to `test` on your system. So, `man test` tells you how to use it. In particular, it is important to put a space after it.

Comment: In bash, however, `[` and `test` are built-ins.  The `/usr/bin/test` command is **almost** identical, but there happen to be some discrepancies.  Therefore, consult `help [` and `help test` rather than `man test`.

Comment: Thanks. But what is quoting for? Why did you quote `"$x"`?

Comment: @bodacydo: Quoting `"$x"` prevents a syntax error if `$x` is empty.

Comment: @bodacydo: it also prevents issues if `$x` contains spaces and other chars that could be interpreted by the shell. It's good practice to *always* quote *all* variable expansions.

Answer (score 2):

Bash cannot adopt the "if x==5" syntax to have the semantics that you want because it is already valid syntax with a different meaning.  'if x==5; then ...; fi' currently sets x to the value '=5' and then executes the commands following then.

In terms of your first question, I advise avoiding the bracket notation completely.  Just do

```
if test "$x" = 5; then
...
fi
```

Also note that 'if test x = 5' will *always* be false, since this is a comparison of the literal string 'x' and the literal string '5'.  You need to use $x to get the value of the variable.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know this before!

Answer (score 1):

Variables in bash should have a $ before them - `if [${x} -eq 5]` should have worked too.

Comment: No, that won't work. There has to be a space after `[` and one before `]`: `if [ ${x} -eq 5 ]` or `if [ $x -eq 5 ]`

Answer (score 1):

sh syntax is actually amazingly flexible, and it is quite possible to get the syntax that you want.  For example, if you want to be able to write "if x == 5", you just need to realize that sh will evaluate that string by invoking a command named 'x' with arguments '==' and '5', and react to the value returned by that function.  The following is probably not a good idea for any sort of production setting, but it may be instructive to understand how this works:

```
#!/bin/sh

declare() {
    eval $1'() {
    case $# in
        0) test $'$1';;
        1) false;;
        *) case $1 in
            =) shift; 
            '$1'=$(expr $*);;
            ==) test "$'$1'" = $2;;
            .=) '$1'="$'$1'$2";;
            +=) '$1'=$(expr $'$1' + $2);;
            -=) '$1'=$(expr $'$1' - $2);;
            *) false;;
        esac
    esac
    }'
}

declare x
x = 5
if x == 4; then echo not printed; fi  
if x == 5; then echo x = $x; fi  # "x = 5"
x += 2;
if x == 5; then echo not printed; fi  
if x == 7; then echo x = $x; fi  # "x = 7"
x = foo
x .= bar
echo x = $x                      # "x = foobar"
x = 4 + 5
echo x = $x                      # "x = 9"
```

The output of the above script is:

```
x = 5
x = 7
x = foobar
x = 9
```

Answer (score 0):

You might find chapter 7.1. Test Constructs in the [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/abs-guide.pdf) helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> Can't bash adopt if x==5; then ...; fi syntax?

In Bash, you can use this syntax which allows you to omit the dollar sign and avoid using `-eq`, so it comes closest to what you'd like to use:

```
if (( x == 5 ))
```

You can even leave out the spaces if you prefer:

```
if ((x==5))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use case/esac

```
case "$x" in
 5) echo "x is 5";;
esac
```